# "squashfs error failed to read block" at the end of liveUSB shutdown (after ENTER)

Tags: live-usb, shutdown

I've encountered the errors after some work on Release **20.04.03 LTS** booted from liveUSB stick made with **Make Startup Disk** of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

```
"squashfs error failed to read block ... -5"
```

Seemingly never ending at the end of liveUSB shutdown (after ENTER).

I've tried google search but found only related install problems. Granted errors at shutdown are not critical as long as system boots and works before shutdown, still could errors be some warning? Squashfs AFAIK need to be unpacked at boot, what is its role during shutdown?

After that I booted again with self-checking (Checking disks: no errors found message) was done (not skipped) at boot time (then USB stick physically is Ok, isn't it?) with default options and immediately initiated shutdown: the system turned off after ENTER w/out above problems.

Comment: if you got the 'remove media & press enter to shutdown' (*that wording isn't correct but it's words to that effect*) your media was unmounted meaning SQUASHFS errors are all you can get in attempts to read the media, on most boxes the box turns off too quickly that people don't get to read the messages - but it is readable on some...   If you got the message 'remove media/hit enter' I'd suggest ignoring the messages, turn the box off (or reset) & quickly eject media & it should boot normally.  Once media is removed; if it boots you're all good.

Answer (score 1):

If you got the 'Please remove the installation medium, then reboot.' (*the message varies on release & asks you to hit enter on some releases; I've taken this from 21.10*) your media was unmounted meaning *SQUASHFS* errors are all you can get in attempts to read the media, on most boxes the box turns off too quickly that people don't get to read the messages - but it is readable on some (*and very readable on boxes that don't turn off*)

If you got the message 'remove media/hit enter' I'd suggest ignoring the messages, turn the box off (or reset) & quickly eject media & it should boot normally.  Once media is removed; if it boots you're all good.

Comment: I also thought it is not a big issue, but asked just in case. I'm still wondering why if I do nothing and shutdown right away PC turns off cleanly, but sometimes when I do some work it does not.

Comment: Depending on release (*impish* & later this won't work on) if I see messages like that I usually SysRq REISU(O for off, B for reboot) and almost never use my power-off button... The messages imply to me the kernel is still running, thus can respond to commands thus I give them via SysRq key combinations to safely shutdown.  Late in the *impish* cycle the SysRq was disabled by default, but it'll work on *focal* or 20.04  (will have to wait & see with 20.04.4 & 5.13 kernel..)

Comment: Could it write in layman's terms what to press for "SysRq REISU(O for off, B for reboot) "?

BTW I usually do not remove the USB stick before hitting ENTER, still if my memory serves me right I still get errors sometimes.

Comment: The linux kernel allows you to give it direct commands from a keyboard (it needs to be a real keyboard; so it won't work on an android phone with keyboard drawn on the screen as that keyboard goes thru the GUI) which use the SysRq key so the kernel knows you're giving it a command, and not your GUI/terminal/desktop etc. As it's not Ubuntu specific; you can grab a phone (or any internet device) & search "magic sysrq" and the wikipedia page is usually at the top; which is as good as any. It will remind you what each letter does; REISUB being a very common one & used as an example on the wiki

Comment: got SysRq working!